# Does the Order of Partial Derivatives Matter When in a Curved/Warped Geometry?

Tags: geometry, derivatives, vector-spaces, vectors, partial-derivative

I am watching a video on general relativity, wherein the author shows how transporting a vector (the bold black one in the bottom left here) in a curved geometry will give different results depending on the path taken (first up then right vs. first right then up), as seen by the two bold black arrows (in the top right) below:

[image: Curved Space]

The vector difference between these two is denoted as **R**. The author goes on to give the following equation for **R**:

[image: Mixed Partials]

From my understanding, the order of partial derivatives does not matter (I'm assuming the geometry is continuous here, as he doesn't state otherwise), so why does the right side of this equation not just always result in the 0 vector? Does this have anything to do with the warped geometry of the background space (in this case, spacetime)? Thanks in advance! The link to the video is [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HJlhBPci_Bg) if you want more context, starting at around 3 minutes for my question.

Comment: These are covariant derivatives and the order matters a lot. My usual suggestion is to learn by reading a textbook, not by watching videos.

Comment: The notation here is not good. But, the long story short is that the failure of covariant derivatives in different directions to commute is *by definition* what we call the curvature.